# UITextView clear attributedText before setting new text

Tags: ios, uitextview, uicolor, nsattributedstring

Hi I am trying to replace the attributedText of a UITextView subclass. I want to change the coloring of the text. to do so the following code is used:

```
AMR_ANSIEscapeHelper *ansiEscapeHelper = [[AMR_ANSIEscapeHelper alloc] init];
    [ansiEscapeHelper setDefaultStringColor:[receiveView.highlightColor objectForKey:@"text"]];
    NSMutableAttributedString *resultString = [receiveView.attributedText copy];

    [receiveView setAttributedText:[ansiEscapeHelper attributedStringWithANSIEscapedString:[ansiEscapeHelper ansiEscapedStringWithAttributedString:resultString]]];
```

Problem is: The text does not get replaced; it just seem to add another layer of text, making the text color very strange. Do i need to assert some clearing before i set the Attributed Text the second time?

Here is how it looks: (The text should not be black, dark green and red)

[image])
[image: An example]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The subclass RegexHighlightView contains another method of coloring the text, therefore multiple colors are painted to the fonts!